# How can I run multiple 'response' functions at a time in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm developing a Gmail Add-on in Google Apps Script that contains a button. This button should be able to open two different URLs in the browser with just one click. How can I achieve this requirement?

I tried to call the 'openURLs', but it doesn't work without 'return', and if I use 'return', only one URL will be opened.

```js
const openLink = (url) => {  
  var actionResponse = CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
    .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
        .setUrl(url)
    .build();    
    return actionResponse;
}

const openURLs = () => {
     openLink("https://www.google.com");
     openLink("https://www.microsoft.com");
}
```

Comment: From what I know, the feature to `open two different URLs in the browser with just one click` is currently not possible using buttons. You may review the documentation of [`setOpenLink(openLink)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/button#setopenlinkopenlink), as it states that `A UI object can only have one of...`.